# Not entering to Stack Overflow using Firefox on Windows

Tags: discussion, ssl, firefox

Up to the last hour, everything is good; I can enter and use Stack Overflow without any hassle, but suddenly now I'm not able to enter this site using Mozilla Firefox, see the below image:

[image]

but on Chrome is fine. I'm using Firefox for some reason. What can I do now?

> Windows 10
>
> Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: no repro in FF on mac

Comment: None here either (FF 60.0.1 x64 on Win 7). Could you provide the certificate details (should be found on that page under advanced). That should allow us to see if it's a local redirect quickly.

Comment: Have you checked your system clock? Is it set to the correct date/time?

Comment: Yes, it is correct @Pekka웃

Comment: It's a _The certificate is not trusted because the issuer is unknown_ error. That shouldn't be the clock, but is likely a redirect by a local problem, e.g. a router wanting you to fill in credentials first. Second most likely would be malware I think.

Comment: No repro, FF 52.8.0 on Vista.  Sorry, it's just you....

Comment: I also faced this problem 1,2 times in last 30 days. But it was automatically solved just after a few minutes. The only thing I did was just refresh the browser....

Comment: Corporate firewall that intercepts SSL traffic? I had such problems with HSTS in the past due to one.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I'm trying to last 2 hours

Comment: This has been happening to a few of my colleagues over the last month on random sites after a Windows 10 update. One workaround that works is to disable/enable your Network Adapter.

Comment: It is a sad commentary on the state of HTTPS.  Do consider trusting what it tells you, especially so when nobody else has this problem.  I've seen several meta questions about a user's browser visiting SO getting infected by malicious javascript.  It seems to be an attractive target for job peddlers, perhaps picked up by visiting one of the vampire sites.  Use a 10 foot pole to operate that Advanced button.

Comment: @HansPassant SO has properly set up HSTS. That advanced button lets you view the certificate, but it _doesn't_ allow you to trust the certificate. Not temporarily, not ever. In Firefox, there's no way to visit a site you've previously visited that has HSTS and an invalid certificate, outside of manually clearing the HSTS cache and then trusting the certificate. So no risk there.

Comment: Still not any luck.